# Clash of clans simultaneous upgrades

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clash of Clans, on Android, I started upgrading my laboratory whilst my hogriders were being upgraded. Did that cancel or postpone the hogriders? I had used 50,000 dark elixir on the hogriders, and hope it is not lost

Comment: There are now several duplicates of this question...

Answer (score 1):

When you upgrade your lab when you have a research going on, the research will continue as the lab is upgraded. If you are online when the lab finishes upgrading, it may display as the upgrade is continuing where it has left off. This is a visual bug and can be fixed by relogging.

Source: [COC Wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Laboratory)

> If you decide to upgrade your Laboratory while there's a research going on, it will continue the research progression. If you happen to be logged on when the lab upgrade completes, it may appear that the upgrade picks up where it left off. Log out and back on to see your troop upgrade progress reach its proper progress level.